# css media queries not working for ipad landscape mode

Tags: ios, css, ipad, media-queries, meta-tags

I have an ipad in which I want to apply media queries when it is in landscape mode. This is what I have tried (I have tried both options.) :

**Option 1:**

```
/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media all and (device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 768px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  .ipad-landscape { color: blue; } /* your css rules for ipad landscape */
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}
```

The above media queries doesn't seem to work when the ipad is in landscape mode.

In header.php file, I am using following meta properties:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the **meta properties or in the media queries above** so that I can apply media queries 
when the ipad is in landscape mode.

Comment: I tried your media queries and both worked for me.

Comment: Its not working for me. Is there any issue with meta properties ?

Answer (score 0):

I would change your css to the following code:

```
/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  /* Styles */
}
```